# Adding featured image to post display widget

Tags: plugins, post-thumbnails, post-type

I have below plugin code that displays custom post types as a recent post widget. I would like this code to also display the summary excerpt of the posts and the featured image of the posts as well. What and where should i add to call featured image and the excerpt text?

I would be glad if you can help.

```
<?php
/**
 * Custom Post Type Recent Posts widget class
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 * @package Custom Post Type Widgets
 */

class WP_Custom_Post_Type_Widgets_Recent_Posts extends WP_Widget {

    public function __construct() {
        $widget_ops = array( 'classname' => 'widget_recent_entries', 'description' => __( 'Your site’s most recent custom Posts.', 'custom-post-type-widgets' ) );
        parent::__construct( 'custom-post-type-recent-posts', __( 'Recent Posts (Custom Post Type)', 'custom-post-type-widgets' ), $widget_ops );
        $this->alt_option_name = 'widget_custom_post_type_recent_posts';
    }

    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        if ( ! isset( $args['widget_id'] ) ) {
            $args['widget_id'] = $this->id;
        }

        $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', empty( $instance['title'] ) ? __( 'Recent Posts', 'custom-post-type-widgets' ) : $instance['title'], $instance, $this->id_base );
        $posttype = ! empty( $instance['posttype'] ) ? $instance['posttype'] : 'post';
        if ( empty( $instance['number'] ) || ! $number = absint( $instance['number'] ) ) {
            $number = 5;
        }
        $show_date = isset( $instance['show_date'] ) ? $instance['show_date'] : false;

        $post_types = get_post_types( array( 'public' => true ), 'objects' );

        if ( array_key_exists( $posttype, (array) $post_types ) ) {
            $r = new WP_Query( apply_filters( 'widget_posts_args', array(
                'post_type' => $posttype,
                'posts_per_page' => $number,
                'no_found_rows' => true,
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
            ) ) );

            if ( $r->have_posts() ) : ?>
                <?php echo $args['before_widget']; ?>
                <?php if ( $title ) {
                    echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];
                } ?>
                <ul>
                <?php while ( $r->have_posts() ) : $r->the_post(); ?>
                    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php get_the_title() ? the_title() : the_ID(); ?></a>
                    <?php if ( $show_date ) : ?>
                        <span class="post-date"><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></span>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    </li>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
                </ul>
                <?php echo $args['after_widget']; ?>
                <?php
                wp_reset_postdata();
            endif;
        }
    }

    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = $old_instance;
        $instance['title'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] );
        $instance['posttype'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['posttype'] );
        $instance['number'] = (int) $new_instance['number'];
        $instance['show_date'] = isset( $new_instance['show_date'] ) ? (bool) $new_instance['show_date'] : false;
        return $instance;
    }

    public function form( $instance ) {
        $title = isset( $instance['title'] ) ? esc_attr( $instance['title'] ) : '';
        $posttype = isset( $instance['posttype'] ) ? $instance['posttype']: 'post';
        $number = isset( $instance['number'] ) ? absint( $instance['number'] ) : 5;
        $show_date = isset( $instance['show_date'] ) ? (bool) $instance['show_date'] : false;
?>
        <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:', 'custom-post-type-widgets' ); ?></label>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" /></p>

        <?php
            $post_types = get_post_types( array( 'public' => true ), 'objects' );

            printf(
                '<p><label for="%1$s">%2$s</label>' .
                '<select class="widefat" id="%1$s" name="%3$s">',
                $this->get_field_id( 'posttype' ),
                __( 'Post Type:', 'custom-post-type-widgets' ),
                $this->get_field_name( 'posttype' )
            );

            foreach ( $post_types as $post_type => $value ) {
                if ( 'attachment' === $post_type ) {
                    continue;
                }

                printf(
                    '<option value="%s"%s>%s</option>',
                    esc_attr( $post_type ),
                    selected( $post_type, $posttype, false ),
                    __( $value->label, 'custom-post-type-widgets' )
                );

            }
            echo '</select></p>';
        ?>

        <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'number' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Number of posts to show:', 'custom-post-type-widgets' ); ?></label>
        <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'number' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'number' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $number; ?>" size="3" /></p>

        <p><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" <?php checked( $show_date ); ?> id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'show_date' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'show_date' ); ?>" />
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'show_date' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Display post date?', 'custom-post-type-widgets' ); ?></label></p>
<?php
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your updated code-

```
/**
 * Custom Post Type Recent Posts widget class
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 * @package Custom Post Type Widgets
 */

class WP_Custom_Post_Type_Widgets_Recent_Posts extends WP_Widget {

    public function __construct() {
        $widget_ops = array( 'classname' => 'widget_recent_entries', 'description' => __( 'Your site’s most recent custom Posts.', 'custom-post-type-widgets' ) );
        parent::__construct( 'custom-post-type-recent-posts', __( 'Recent Posts (Custom Post Type)', 'custom-post-type-widgets' ), $widget_ops );
        $this->alt_option_name = 'widget_custom_post_type_recent_posts';
    }

    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        if ( ! isset( $args['widget_id'] ) ) {
            $args['widget_id'] = $this->id;
        }

        $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', empty( $instance['title'] ) ? __( 'Recent Posts', 'custom-post-type-widgets' ) : $instance['title'], $instance, $this->id_base );
        $posttype = ! empty( $instance['posttype'] ) ? $instance['posttype'] : 'post';
        if ( empty( $instance['number'] ) || ! $number = absint( $instance['number'] ) ) {
            $number = 5;
        }
        $show_date = isset( $instance['show_date'] ) ? $instance['show_date'] : false;

        $post_types = get_post_types( array( 'public' => true ), 'objects' );

        if ( array_key_exists( $posttype, (array) $post_types ) ) {
            $r = new WP_Query( apply_filters( 'widget_posts_args', array(
                'post_type' => $posttype,
                'posts_per_page' => $number,
                'no_found_rows' => true,
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
            ) ) );

            if ( $r->have_posts() ) : ?>
                <?php echo $args['before_widget']; ?>
                <?php if ( $title ) {
                    echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];
                } ?>
                <ul>
                    <?php while ( $r->have_posts() ) : $r->the_post(); ?>
                        <li>
                            <?php has_post_thumbnail() ? the_post_thumbnail() : ''?>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php get_the_title() ? the_title() : the_ID(); ?></a>
                            <?php if ( $show_date ) : ?>
                                <span class="post-date"><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></span>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </li>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                </ul>
                <?php echo $args['after_widget']; ?>
                <?php
                wp_reset_postdata();
            endif;
        }
    }

    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = $old_instance;
        $instance['title'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] );
        $instance['posttype'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['posttype'] );
        $instance['number'] = (int) $new_instance['number'];
        $instance['show_date'] = isset( $new_instance['show_date'] ) ? (bool) $new_instance['show_date'] : false;
        return $instance;
    }

    public function form( $instance ) {
        $title = isset( $instance['title'] ) ? esc_attr( $instance['title'] ) : '';
        $posttype = isset( $instance['posttype'] ) ? $instance['posttype']: 'post';
        $number = isset( $instance['number'] ) ? absint( $instance['number'] ) : 5;
        $show_date = isset( $instance['show_date'] ) ? (bool) $instance['show_date'] : false;
        ?>
        <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:', 'custom-post-type-widgets' ); ?></label>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" /></p>

        <?php
        $post_types = get_post_types( array( 'public' => true ), 'objects' );

        printf(
            '<p><label for="%1$s">%2$s</label>' .
            '<select class="widefat" id="%1$s" name="%3$s">',
            $this->get_field_id( 'posttype' ),
            __( 'Post Type:', 'custom-post-type-widgets' ),
            $this->get_field_name( 'posttype' )
        );

        foreach ( $post_types as $post_type => $value ) {
            if ( 'attachment' === $post_type ) {
                continue;
            }

            printf(
                '<option value="%s"%s>%s</option>',
                esc_attr( $post_type ),
                selected( $post_type, $posttype, false ),
                __( $value->label, 'custom-post-type-widgets' )
            );

        }
        echo '</select></p>';
        ?>

        <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'number' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Number of posts to show:', 'custom-post-type-widgets' ); ?></label>
            <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'number' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'number' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $number; ?>" size="3" /></p>

        <p><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" <?php checked( $show_date ); ?> id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'show_date' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'show_date' ); ?>" />
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'show_date' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Display post date?', 'custom-post-type-widgets' ); ?></label></p>
        <?php
    }
}
```

The main tricks is here at this part-

```
<li>
    <?php has_post_thumbnail() ? the_post_thumbnail() : ''?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php get_the_title() ? the_title() : the_ID(); ?></a>
    <?php if ( $show_date ) : ?>
        <span class="post-date"><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></span>
    <?php endif; ?>
</li>
```